# How to do a query with a parameter coming from another JSP

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlets

I'm practicing with the development of a simple Web application using PostgreSQL and JSP.

Let me explain briefly.

I have a table "users" which contains info about football players (name, surname, country).

I have this JSP which does a query to obtain all the countries of the players contained in the table. Then the JSP shows each country as a link.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="model.User"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Choose a Country</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Choose a Country</h1>
        <p>

<% 
       Connection c = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/firstapp",
                           "postgres", "admin");

         c.setAutoCommit(false);
         System.out.println("Opened database successfully" +"\n");

         stmt = c.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT country FROM users;");

         while (rs.next() ) {
            //int id = rs.getInt("player_id");
            String  country = rs.getString("country");

            User u = (User) request.getAttribute("user"); %>

            <a href="./showCountry.jsp"><% out.print(country); %></a>

            <br/>
       <% 
               }
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         c.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
       }%>

</p>
    </body>
```

What I want is the following: when I click on one of the countries (which is a link) in the list, another JSP should do another query like this:

```
SELECT * from users where country = *country chosen from the first JSP*
```

So the second JSP should take in some way the chosen country from the first JSP

This is my second JSP

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
        import="model.User"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>


    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Players from chosen country</title>
        <input Type="BUTTON" Value="Home Page" onclick="location.href='index.html'"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Players from chosen country</h1>
        <p>
<% 
       Connection c = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try {
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
           c = DriverManager
                   .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/firstapp",
                           "postgres", "admin");

         c.setAutoCommit(false);
         System.out.println("Opened database successfully" +"\n");

         stmt = c.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE country = *chosen country*;" );

         while (rs.next() ) {
            int id = rs.getInt("user_id");
            String  firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
            String  lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
            String  country = rs.getString("country");



    User u = (User) request.getAttribute("user"); %>


First Name: <% out.print(firstname); %> <br/>
Last Name: <% out.print(lastname); %> <br/>
Country: <% out.print(country); %> <br/>
<p/>
       <% 
               }
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         c.close();

       } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
       }%>

</p>
</body>
```

How can I pass the chosen country from one JSP to the other one?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following code in your first code

From

```
 <a href="./showCountry.jsp"><% out.print(country); %></a>
```

To

```
 <a href="./showCountry.jsp?country=<%=country%>"><% out.print(country); %></a>
```

You can the country value in second.jsp using following:

```
String country = request.getParameter("country");
```

Now you can pass the country variable to Query like the following

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE country ='"+country+"';" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your link in the first jsp to

```
<a href="./showCountry.jsp?country=<% out.print(country); %>">
    <% out.print(country); %>
</a>
```

In the second jsp, use `request.getParameter("country")` to get the value that was sent from the first jsp

Comment: Ok but how do I add the country variable in the query?